# Notification replaces old in android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I receiving notification using GCM in android. When i get two notifications together, second replaces the first notification. How to stack the notification?

I tried different id for notify. hoe to solve this?

```
    notify ( int id, Notification notification)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem generally occurs if the notification Id is same for 2 notifications.

Try giving timestamp as value to notificationId so that for every GCM message the

notification ID will be unique.

Just go through your code once,I think there might be some small mistake regarding

notification Id.

I hope it helps.

Comment: If i send the different tag of notify(tag, notification) method, it will send seperate notificatioms?

Comment: Well I didn't get your point.Can you please elaborate a bit more on your last comment.

Comment: Programmatically, if i set unique id for notification like, notify(id, notification) method, it will send seperate notificatioms?

Comment: Yes it will send separate notifications for unique notification id.Try giving timestamps which will be unique always.